# How to use a Post Build Event to delete $(TargetDir)

Tags: visual-studio, post-build-event

Scenario:

We have an assembly which is distributed to 2 different customers, and within the post build event, I am copying $(TargetDir) to 2 different directories, which means $(TargetDir) becomes redundant.

My script looks like this:

```
    start /min xcopy "$(TargetDir)*.*" "$(TargetDir)..\Folder1" /s /y /i
    start /min xcopy "$(TargetDir)*.*" "$(TargetDir)..\Folder2"  /s /y /i
```

I am then trying to delete $(TargetDir) using:

```
    start /min rd /s /q "$(TargetDir)"
```

However, this fails with "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

Have also tried to use:

```
    attrib -R "$(TargetDir)*.*" /S
```

prior to delete, but still no joy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anti-malware is forever the problem with post-builds like this, it isn't done yet with scanning executable files that seemingly appeared from nowhere. The directory cannot be destroyed until all files are removed, that cannot happen until the scan is completed.

There is more than one workaround you can consider:

- Change $(TargetDir) to Folder1 so you don't have extra copies and don't have to delete anything.
- Only delete the files and not the directory.
- Don't delete anything since that just forces the project to be rebuilt every single time.
- Tell the user to add an exclusion for the build directory.

Start with the 4th bullet, best way to find out that it is indeed the user's anti-malware product that causes this problem.  If it is Avast then look no further, that blight to humankind does not belong on a programmer's machine.